# Automatically add the README while creating the new project in GitLab

Tags: git, automation, push, project, git-commit

I am currently using the GitLab CE 8.14.3. Here when I create the new project in the Gitlab every time I need to add the readme file manually. I want to automate this function. That is When I create the new project in the GitLab automatically Readme also added in the master branch. I used the below link to add the readme file

[image]

I need it because only master and the owner can able to push into the master branch. If Developer tried to add the readme file means he get below error

[image]

I googled regarding this but I don't get the proper idea about it. Have anyone idea about this automation process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a [feature request for GitLab CE](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/25631) for a repo template (which would include a README), but... this has been [moved as a EE one](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/1602)

In the meantime, as [explained here](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/) (for GitHub, but the same applies to GitLab), you can clone a template repo, and push it to your new GitLab (empty) repo.